# Generic Object Getter

Tags: java, generics

I have the following class structure:

```
public class BasePage {
    ...
}

public class PageA extends BasePage {
    ...
    public void doStuffA() {}
}

public class PageB extends BasePage {
    ...
    public void doStuffB() {}
}
```

Then I have another class that contains some getters/setters:

```
public class TestBase {

private static BasePage currentPage;

public static <T extends BasePage> T getCurrentPage() {
    return (T) currentPage;
}

public static void <T extends BasePage> setBasePage(T page) {
    currentPage = page
}
```

And inside my tests I'd like use the methods like so:

```
TestBase.getCurrentPage<PageA>().doStuffA()
```

But IntelliJ does not seem to like that last syntax.  What am I doing wrong?

> It says: Cannot resolve symbol 'getCurrentPage'

It does seem to be able to resolve `TestBase.getCurrentPage()` but I can't access either `doStuff` methods.

Comment: `IntelliJ does not seem to like that last syntax` Why? What's it saying?

Comment: do you get any syntax error or exception .please share it may be helpful..

Comment: Isn't it `TestBase.<PageA>getCurrentPage().doStuffA();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Quick fix

As [@Andrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5647260/andrew-li) pointed out, this is how you can specify a generic type for a static method:

```
TestBase.<PageA>getCurrentPage().doStuffA();
```

This is the very same syntax we use at `Collections.emptyList()` :

```
Collections.<String>emptyList();
```

#### Redesign

I'm a little concerned that this isn't really what you need. I.e. you can specify a type for the `getCurrentPage()`, and another for `setCurrentPage()`. In both of the cases you're `<T extends BasePage>`. However, this is a method-level type, so you can change them by each invocation. Say for instance, this passes the compiler. On the other hand, it will give you a `ClassCastException`:

```
TestBase.<PageB>setBasePage(new PageB());
TestBase.<PageA>getCurrentPage().doStuffA(); // Fine for the compiler. Throws an Exception though
```

I would rewrite `currentPage` as a non-static field and I'd use a class-level type for this case:

```
public class TestBase <T extends BasePage> {

    private T currentPage;

    public T getCurrentPage() {
        return currentPage;
    }

    public void setBasePage(T page) {
        currentPage = page;
    }

}
```

It makes the syntax easy:

```
TestBase<PageA> testBase = new TestBase<>(); // specify the page type
testBase.setBasePage(new PageA());
testBase.getCurrentPage().doStuffA(); // easy-peasy
```

Also, the compiler will spot type errors for you:

```
TestBase<PageA> testBase = new TestBase<>(); // specify the page type
testBase.setBasePage(new PageB()); // compiler error
```

Answer (score 3):

`(PageA)TestBase.getCurrentPage().doStuffA()`

Comment: Just a note to this - In most cases it is a good idea to check if `TestBase.getCurrentPage() instanceof PageA` so you don't get runtime errors.